# PHP: cannot INSERT into MYSQL table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

The below MYSQL INSERT command, using PDO, just fails. And after it fails and reports so, the DROP TABLE command also fails. I just can't get what's wrong with the code :/

```
$sql = $db2->prepare(
'INSERT INTO citizens_12_01_12
(login, rank, xp, level, citizenship, totalDamage, economySkill, damageToday, strength) 
VALUES 
(:login, :rank, :xp, :citizenship, :totalDamage, :economySkill, :damageToday, :strength)'
);
$sql->bindParam(':strength', $api->strength, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':damageToday', $api->damageToday, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':economySkill', $api->economySkill, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':totalDamage', $api->totalDamage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//$sql->bindValue(':organization', api->organization, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$sql->bindParam(':citizenship', $api->citizenship, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':level', $api->level, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':xp', $api->xp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':login', $api->login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':rank', $api->rank, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($sql->execute()) {
    echo "Query succeeded.";
} else {
    echo "Query failed.";
    $db2->query("DROP TABLE 'citizens_12_01_12'");
}
```

Following error in error_log:

```
PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute() [<a href='pdostatement.execute'>pdostatement.execute</a>]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in .../getcitizens.php on line 55
```

Line 55 is the $sql->execute() line

Comment: Can you post the error? If there isn't one (outputted to you via GUI), check your error log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing your variable `:level` in the insert statement.

It should be:

```
$sql = $db2->prepare(
'INSERT INTO citizens_12_01_12
(login, rank, xp, level, citizenship, totalDamage, economySkill, damageToday, strength) 
VALUES 
(:login, :rank, :xp, :level, :citizenship, :totalDamage, :economySkill, :damageToday, :strength)'
);
```

Comment: Jesus. That's why I shouldn't code at almost 2 in the morning! Thankyou kindly.